# Refactor this code to not place tainted, user-controlled data in the header

Tags: java, regex, security, header, sonarqube

I'm trying to add custom header in my HTTPHeader like below

```
Enumeration<String> headerNames = request.getHeaderNames();
while (headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
    String headerName = headerNames.nextElement();
    if (headerName.equalsIgnoreCase("SampleHeader"){
        headers.add(headerName, request.getHeader(headerName));
    }
}
```

but I'm getting below bug while running sonar.

"Refactor this code to not place tainted, user-controlled data in the header."

I think adding a regex might solve my problem, but I had two problems.

1. I'm need to write an regex that allow alphabets, number and . , ! - _  But I'm unable to create one.
2. I'm not sure checking using some regex will debinately solve my problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [OWASP Encoder](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.owasp.encoder/encoder) to encode user input:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.owasp.encoder</groupId>
    <artifactId>encoder</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Add [Encode.forJava(userInput)](https://owasp.org/owasp-java-encoder/encoder/apidocs/org/owasp/encoder/Encode.html#forJava-java.lang.String-) for user input which will:

> Encodes for a Java string. This method will use "\b", "\t", "\r",
> "\f", "\n", """, "'", "\", octal and unicode escapes. Valid
> surrogate pairing is not checked. The caller must provide the
> enclosing quotation characters. This method is useful for when writing
> code generators and outputting debug messages.

So in your case it may be:

```
Enumeration<String> headerNames = request.getHeaderNames();
while (headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
    String headerName = Encode.forJava(headerNames.nextElement());
    if (headerName.equalsIgnoreCase("SampleHeader"){
        headers.add(headerName, request.getHeader(headerName));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because you are using a header name ("SampleHeader") to make a logical decision in your code.

User provided data, such as URL parameters, POST data payloads or cookies, should always be considered untrusted and tainted. Applications logging tainted data could enable an attacker to inject characters that would break the log file pattern. This could be used to block monitors and SIEM (Security Information and Event Management) systems from detecting other malicious events.

In this case if I wanted to fool your program into adding a new header into the `headers` list I would simply need to send a curl like this:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost/your/path --header 'SampleHeader: someValue'
```

This problem could be mitigated by sanitizing the user provided data before logging it.

What SonarQube is trying to tell you is that you are exposing your logic to input from the clients. A better solution would be to refactor your code to not depend on a specific header from the client to perform some action. Its hard to suggest sample code without seeing a little more of the codebase.

Hope this helps!